# Completely removing a django app that has dot notation

Tags: python, django

I want to remove the `django.contrib.comments` app from a project I'm working on. I tried:

```
$ python manage.py sqlclear django.contrib.comments
```

on the shell but got:

> Error: App with label django.contrib.comments could not be found. Are
>   you sure your INSTALLED_APPS setting is correct?

I have double checked my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and indeed `django.contrib.comments` is present.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app_name is actually just the last element of the file path. So `comments` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could run

```
python manage.py reset app_name
```

Then remove app_name from your installed apps.